# Subversion - Reference to a project without checking it out?

Tags: svn

I'd love to Google this (I've tried) but I'm not sure what it is called, let alone how to do it.

Consider:

```
project A
project B
```

I am working on project A, that happens to need project B. How, do I without checking out project B with project A, have a reference to it?

In other words, there is a way (I experienced it on placement) that allows you to use a project within a project and if someone was to update that project you'd get the changes. Basically it means you don't have to worry about falling out of date or managing two copies of something.

No need (but if you can/want) explain, just a link or name will sort myself out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is what [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) is for. You still need a copy of project B, but it resides in it's own, separate repository.

Comment: Should be noted that its still a checkout though i.e. if you so chose you could (in theory) commit changes from the external bit (to its repository).

Comment: Yeah that's fine - I'm the sole author of both projects so its fine. I just didn't want to manage two separate versions.

Comment: But be careful. If you don't specify an explicit revision, snv externals always point to the actual head revision. That means, if you ever go back to a specific revision of project A, this will still reference the now actual head revision of project B.

Answer (score 0):

If both projects live in the same repository, then simply check out a directory that contains BOTH projects.

For example, lets say the svn repository starts with a directory called "trunk", and this directory contains projectA and projectB directories.  If you check out "trunk", then you will be able to work on A, or B and get notified of changes in both projects when you update "trunk".